# mysql query get latest record ignore the old entry

Tags: mysql

need help getting all the latest record except the old entry by the same mobile numbers and same code:

```
id  |   mobile_number   |   code    |   chapter_id
1   |   123123          |   3       |   1
2   |   123124          |   4       |   1
3   |   123123          |   4       |   1
4   |   123124          |   3       |   1
5   |   123122          |   3       |   1
```

Output should like this

```
1   |   123123          |   3       |   1
3   |   123123          |   4       |   1
4   |   123124          |   3       |   1
5   |   123122          |   3       |   1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try this query.

```
SELECT `id`,`mobile_number`,`code`,`chapter_id`
FROM test_table 
WHERE id in (SELECT MAX(id) from test_table GROUP BY `mobile_number`)
```

This maybe useful for you.

Comment: i edited my questions: "except the old entry by the same mobile numbers and same code"

Comment: @Cris i think some thing wrong in your current output. as per you say you need same numbers and same code also display second record also its different for 4th record

Comment: @Cris this query is for you want.

SELECT `id`,`mobile_number`,`code`,`chapter_id`
FROM test_table
WHERE id in (SELECT MAX(id) from test_table GROUP BY `mobile_number`,`code`)

please check and let me know.

Comment: sorry, i mean combination of numbers and code, your query actually work for me. thanks

Comment: @Cris ok, no problem please check above query and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY mobile_number  ORDER BY code DESC
```

Comment: i edited my questions: "except the old entry by the same mobile numbers and same code"

Answer (score 0):

You might try this :

```
select id,mobile_number,code,chapter_id from(
    select id,mobile_number,code,chapter_id,
    case when mobile_number = @ck then @rownum := @rownum+1 else @rownum:=0 end as n,
    @ck:= mobile_number as c
    from yourtable
    inner join(select @rownum :=0 ,@id := '') as x
    order by mobile_number,id desc
)as t
where n = 0
```